# avoid round off

Tags: vb.net, arraylist, sum, rounding

how to avoid rounding off numbers

Code below

```
Dim acc = 0
Dim i 
Dim x() = {699.68, 632.70}
  For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
    acc = acc + x(i)
  Next

  console.writeline(acc)
```

return : 1333

thanks
inchikka

Comment: Have you tried `Dim acc = 0.0` ?

Answer (score 1):

`acc` is implicitly defined as integer because you initialize it with 0, which is an integer.

You should define `acc` explicitly as a floating-point number. I'm not sure about the VB syntax, but I guess it's something like:

```
Dim acc as Double
```

or

```
Dim acc = 0.0
```

Comment: Thanks Ilya I defined  Dim acc As Double  and  Dim aa() As Double

Answer (score 1):

Ilya Kogan is correct, the issue is that you were not explicitly defining your variables.

The only thing to add is that in VB it's a *really* good idea to use the `Option Explicit` statement, which requires that variables be defined. Even better, there's a setting you can turn on which automatically adds that to your code in every new project. I'm not sure what version of VB you're running, but here's the link to the MSDN article explaining how to enable this option (depending on what version of VB you have, click on "Other Versions" at the top of the page and select yours as the instructions vary):

[MSDN Option Explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

In the off chance you're running VB6, the sequence is a little different (and apparently not MSDN documented). Go to: Tools -> Options and check Require Variable Declaration.